# Calculation for more than one column in data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, average

***Target***

I have only been using Pandas for a few days and am trying to use `.loc` and `.mean()` to calculate the average for multiple columns, and represent the value in a new row under the columns.

---

***My Attempt***

When finding the average of a single column, and using the following code...:

```
df.loc['Average', 'Column1'] = df['Column1'].mean()
```

^ ... The output is as expected.

---

However, When I attempt to add an additional column to find the average of, as such:

```
df.loc['Average', 'Column1', 'Column2'] = df['Column1', 'Column2'].mean()
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: ('Column1', 'Column2')
```

I'm assuming there is a very easy solution - I'm just pretty new at this stage.

---

***Expected Output***:

```
# ...... is replaced with numbers

            Column1       Column2
1           .......       .......
2           .......       .......
3           .......       .......
...         .......       .......
Average     #SomeFloat    #AnotherFloat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap multiple column names in a list:

```
df.loc['Average', ['Column1', 'Column2']] = df[['Column1', 'Column2']].mean()
```

Comment: Yes. If you don't do that, it will be treated as a tuple and thus multi index in pandas, as in python, comma creates tuples. And that is the reason you see the keyError which means,  `(Column1, Column2)`  is treated as a multi index and it doesn't exist in the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

**mean** operates only on a single input.  Perhaps the most direct way to get the result you want is to use a list of columns:

```
df[['Column1', 'Column2']].mean()
```

You could also compute them individually, add those means, and divide by 2, but that's more typing.